# Redirect back to application from redirect_uri page

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm working on building a connect with [Strava](https://strava.github.io/api/v3/oauth/) button, however, I'm new to Swift and iOS development and I'm not sure how to redirect back to the application from the web view of redirect_uri.

I would appreciate any help.